# Solving for triangle side length with limited information

Tags: geometry, triangles

I have a geometry question which I am fairly certain has a solution, but I can't for the life of me figure out what it is.

[image: The problem layout]

I would like to find the length of $|\vec{AB}|$.

I have as givens:

1. $|\vec{AD}|$
2. $|\vec{BD}|$
3. $|\vec{AC}|$
4. $|\vec{AC}| = |\vec{BC}|$
5. $\vec{CD}$ is vertical
6. $\vec{AB}$ is vertical

I've added the line $\vec{EC}$ because I think it will be useful. I believe that there is a solution because when I draw this in a CAD program and enter the constraints it displays as fully defined, however I can't figure out how to calculate the length of AB myself.

Any suggestions or insights that you can provide are much appreciated. Thank you for reading!

**Edited:** Added that AB is vertical. I neglected to include that information in the original post.

Comment: $\vec{CD}$ being "vertical" doesn't help on its own. Do we also know that, say, $\vec{AB}$ is "vertical"? and/or that $\vec{CE}$ is "horizontal"?

Comment: If AB and CD are parallel you can use the cosine rule in triangles ACD and BCD to get two equations relating the distance CD and the angle $\theta$, where $2\theta$ is the angle ACB.

Comment: Yes! Thank you. Fantastic point. We know that AB is vertical and that AB and CD are parallel. I will update the question to include that information. I hadn't realized that the CAD program was adding that constraint automatically, and in the real world situation that it is based on that's a valid assumption.

Comment: I'm still not sure I see how that let's me solve for AB :(...Wouldn't using the cosine rule give me two equations with different values for theta?

Comment: ABD and BDC will provide one equation for AB and DC. ABC and ADC will provide you the second equation.

Comment: Is this using the cosine rule? Which angle is θ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the solution of a more general problem is equally easy, we drop the condition $AC=BC$. To simplify the notation we introduce:
$$
AB=a,\quad AD=b,\quad BD=c,\quad AC=d,\quad BC=e.
$$
Besides
$$
\angle ADB=\theta_1,\quad \angle ACB=\theta_2. 
$$

For the trapezoid $ABCD$ we have:
$$
\begin{align}
&b^2+c^2-a^2=2bc\cos\theta_1;\\
&d^2+e^2-a^2=2de\cos\theta_2;\\
&bc\sin\theta_1=de\sin\theta_2.
\end{align}
$$
The first two equations is the cosine theorem, and the last one follows from the equality of the areas of the triangles $ACB$ and $ADB$.

Eliminating the angles one obtains the equation:
$$
b^2c^2\left[1-\left(\frac{b^2+c^2-a^2}{2bc}\right)^2\right]=
d^2e^2\left[1-\left(\frac{d^2+e^2-a^2}{2de}\right)^2\right],
$$
which after straightforward algebra results in:
$$
a^2=\frac{(b^2-c^2)^2-(d^2-e^2)^2}{2(b^2+c^2-d^2-e^2)}.
$$

In your case the substitution $e=d$ will further simplify the result.

Comment: Thank you! Dropping the condition that AC = BC is BRILLIANT. It ends up making a huge difference in what I am trying to do. Thank you so much!

Comment: I am very glad that it was helpful.